# paper.Tool is not working on Multiple canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, drag, paperjs

I have two canvas the first one is working good, but when I initialize the second one the paper.Tool does not work properly, sometimes the event onMouseMove works others not.

```
var dataLoad;
var mypapers = []
$(document).ready(function () {
    dataLoad = new DataLoad();
    mypapers[0] = new paper.PaperScope();
    mypapers[1] = new paper.PaperScope();
    mypapers[0].setup(document.getElementById('dataCanvas'));
    dataLoad.Init();
});


  // "returnedData" THIS ARRAY COMES FROM AN AJAX CALL
  DataLoad.prototype = {
      Init: function () {
         var self = this;
         var paperData = new 
         DataReader(document.getElementById('dataCanvas'));
         paperData.Init(returnedData[i],mypapers[0]);
         paperData.Draw(true);
         self.datas.push(paperData);
      }
   });
```

Till here everything is good the first canvas is populated with the graphics I setted.

```
DataReader.prototype = {
  Init: function (data,mypaper) {
    var self = this;
    paper = mypaper;
    self.paper = paper;
    self.toolPan = new self.paper.Tool()
    self.toolPan.activate();
    self.toolPan.onMouseDrag = function (event) {
       var delta = event.downPoint.subtract(event.point)
       self.paper.view.scrollBy(delta)
    };

    self.toolPan.onMouseMove = function (event) {
        self.OnMouseMove(event);
    };
     self.toolPan.onMouseUp = function (event) {
        // AFTER MAKE A SELECTION OF ITEMS IN THE CANVAS CALLING THE SECOND CANVAS
        var core = self.HighlightElementsInBox();
        self.dc = new DefineComponent();
        self.dc.Init(core);
        $('#DCCanvas').modal('toggle'); // THE CANVAS IS INSIDE THIS  BOOTSTRAP MODAL
    }
  }
```

});

```
/* this initialize the second canvas that basically creates another instance of the same prototype i use to manipulate paperjs in the first canvas */

DefineComponent.prototype = {
  Init: function (dataCore) {
    var self = this;
    mypapers[1].setup(document.getElementById('DCCanvas')); // setting second canvas
    var paperDataDC = new DataReader(document.getElementById('DCCanvas'));
    paperDataDC.Init(dataCore,mypapers[1]);
    paperDataDC.Draw(true);
    self.datas.push(paperDatasDC);
  }
```

});

In this second canvas all is drawn correctly, but the events `onmousedrag` and `onmousemove` does not works properly the first one move the canvas in another position where the mouse is not and `mousemove` works only in some places of the canvas not in all.

Comment: No experts in paperjs??????

Comment: i think its good if you try and create a minimal example - showing your question -  here at stackoverflow as 'code snippet' or externally as [jsfiddle (link to a simple paper.js example)](https://jsfiddle.net/s_light/5ubkj3yd/) or something similar - so that others can easily build up or debug your code..

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating two different paperScopes you will need to toggle between them when working with one or the other.

You are saving both paperScopes inside "mypapers" array

```
mypapers[0] = new paper.PaperScope();
mypapers[1] = new paper.PaperScope();
```

So to use any of those you should do

```
mypapers[0].activate();
// or
mypapers[1].activate();
```

Check out [this](https://jsbin.com/mavizosaxu/edit?html,js,output) (min setup) example of what I mean above.

Also, follow stefan's suggestion if you want more help on this since it's hard for people to try to help without a minimal working example